# C - Valgrind found memory leak, but it should not have

Tags: c, memory-leaks

For a few days now i have been trying to clean up memory leaks in my system. But this one memory leak has been bugging me.

Problem: Valgrind is reporting a memory leak:

```
==28423== 10,988 (2,624 direct, 8,364 indirect) bytes in 82 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 405 of 409
==28423==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28423==    by 0x5553780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==28423==    by 0x1B432E56: janus_audiobridge_create_user_secret (janus_audiobridge_room_helper.c:641)
==28423==    by 0x1B4250B3: janus_audiobridge_init (janus_audiobridge.c:281)
==28423==    by 0x4111BF: main (janus.c:3898)
```

Heres `janus_audiobridge_create_user_secret (janus_audiobridge_room_helper.c:641):`

```
method_user_secret_error_case *janus_audiobridge_create_user_secret(PGconn *conn, janus_audiobridge_user_secret_model *user_secret_model, gboolean insert_in_db) {
    JANUS_LOG(LOG_VERB, "Creating user_secret\n");

    /* Create the audio bridge secret */
    janus_audiobridge_user_secret *user_secret = g_malloc0(sizeof(janus_audiobridge_user_secret));
    method_user_secret_error_case *error = g_malloc0(sizeof(method_user_secret_error_case));
    if (user_secret_model->user_secret) {
        user_secret->user_secret = g_strdup(user_secret_model->user_secret);
    } else {
        gchar *new_secret = randstring((size_t)100);
        user_secret->user_secret = g_strdup(new_secret);
        user_secret_model->user_secret = g_strdup(new_secret); // Model is necesarry for saving to database
        g_free(new_secret);
    }
    user_secret->user_ip = g_strdup(user_secret_model->user_ip);
    user_secret->created_at = user_secret_model->created_at;
    if (insert_in_db) {
        // Save to db
        int save_err = janus_audiobridge_create_user_secret_db(conn, user_secret_model);
        if (save_err == 0) {
            JANUS_LOG(LOG_ERR, "Failed to save to database.\n");
            g_free(user_secret->user_secret);
            g_free(user_secret->user_ip);
            g_free(user_secret);
            const gchar *error_message = "Error saving to database.\n";
            error->error = JANUS_AUDIOBRIDGE_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ERROR;
            error->error_message = error_message;
            return error;  
        }
    }

    g_hash_table_insert(user_secrets, g_strdup(user_secret->user_secret), user_secret);
    // Prepare response
    const gchar *error_message = "";
    error->error = 0;
    error->error_message = error_message;
    error->user_secret = user_secret;

    return error;
}
```

And of course `janus_audiobridge_init (janus_audiobridge.c:281)`:

```
/* Fetch all user_secrets from database */  
const gchar *select_all_user_secrets_query = "SELECT * FROM user_secrets;";
GHashTable *user_secrets_db = user_secrets_query(conn, select_all_user_secrets_query);
// Create user secrets from database
g_hash_table_iter_init(&iter, user_secrets_db);
while (g_hash_table_iter_next(&iter, NULL, &value)) {
    janus_audiobridge_user_secret_model *db_user_secret = value;
    method_user_secret_error_case *create_resp = janus_audiobridge_create_user_secret(conn, db_user_secret, (gboolean)FALSE);
    if (create_resp->error != 0) {
        JANUS_LOG(LOG_ERR, "Error: %s\n", create_resp->error_message); 
    }

    g_free(db_user_secret->user_secret);
    g_free(db_user_secret->user_ip);
    g_free(db_user_secret);
    g_free(create_resp);
}
// Free the hashtable of entries from database
g_hash_table_destroy(user_secrets_db);
```

So my question is following: Why valgrind shows that i am leaking memory even tho, i am freeing it with g_free? The other `user_secret` struct is stored in HashTable, so i can't free it, because i am using it later.

P.S I don't free user_secret at any place at the code at this time, because i use it consistently in lifetime of my system.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Sorry, i forgot to provide which line is it:
641 line is -

```
janus_audiobridge_user_secret *user_secret = g_malloc0(sizeof(janus_audiobridge_user_secret));
```

and 281:

```
method_user_secret_error_case *create_resp = janus_audiobridge_create_user_secret(conn, db_user_secret, (gboolean)FALSE);
```

Comment: memory allocated in create_user_secret is leaking, line 641 - which one is it?

Comment: Valgrind works by providing its own memory management functions in place of the standard library's.  It is therefore extremely reliable about identifying memory leaks: if it says you are leaking memory then the only conclusion you should consider is that you are leaking memory.

Comment: Which `g_malloc0()` call is on line 641?

Comment: @Attie Updated my post

Comment: Do you ever `free()` the returned `error->user_secret`? Your PS states that you don't free `user_secret`, so isn't that likely to be your leak?

Comment: Hey, I free `g_free(create_resp);` - This is the error. But why do i have to free `error->user_secret`? Isn't it just a pointer to the struct(which is used in hastable)? I don't free user_secret at all, as it is used in hashtable, which i user troughout my app.

Comment: If after adding that `g_free()` you do not get new complaints from valgrind about invalid memory accesses, then it follows that you *do not* use the pointer recorded in your hash table.  Moreover, although I'm having a bit of difficulty following your code, it appears that you in fact destroy the hash table after iterating over it, but as far as I am aware, that does not cause any memory pointed to by the table's contents to be freed.

Comment: After adding `g_free(create_resp->user_secret)`, i go from 10 errors to 25(and the old error is still there). So i think that is not the problem. What do you think?

Comment: The issue is quite simple. For every call to malloc and friends, you should be able to point out the corresponding call to free.  And by call I mean a dynamic occurrence of a call, not a static occurrence.

Comment: I think you have discovered (some of) the objects that were leaking.  It is not clear whether you have discovered the correct fix for the leak.

Comment: @n.m. But if i don't need to free the memory for that specific thing? For example i need user_secrets to live as long as the app is running. And on app destroy i just destroy the hashtable.

Comment: So it's quite easy to check yourself. Print every pointer that you obtain on the line valgrind trlls you. Also print every pointer before calling the corresponding free(). In the end, two printed lists of pointers should match. If they don't, you are not freeing some of them. Trace where each one goes after allocation.

Comment: If you "_need `user_secrets` to live as long as the app is running_" (which is questionable... how many? when do you stop making them? etc...), then you need to `free()` them when the application exits. Otherwise you will not get a 'clean' report from `valgrind`. As @John says, you need to free them, but probably not _there_.

Comment: If spurious valgrind warnings is something you agree to live with, go ahead and don't free it. Valgrind cannot know whether you need that memory till the end or not, it reports all things not freed.

Comment: " I don't free user_secret at any place" and Valgrind will report that because it just sees that it hasn't been freed when the program ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SiggiSv , @n.m and @Attie

After freeing the user secrets on janus_destroy, valgrind stopped reporting that memory leak. So that was more of a problem with me not knowing how valgrind works. Thanks again for everybody who helped.

Here's the code, if somebody finds it usefull:

```
  // Free user secret memory - So Valgrind Doesn't register memory leak
  // We do this, because we don't delete user secret in janus logic, and valgrind sees that as a memory leak
    GHashTableIter iter;
    gpointer value;
    g_hash_table_iter_init(&iter, user_secrets);
    while (g_hash_table_iter_next(&iter, NULL, &value)) {
        janus_audiobridge_user_secret *user_secret = value;
        g_free(user_secret->user_secret);
        g_free(user_secret->user_ip);
        g_free(user_secret);
    }
    g_hash_table_destroy(user_secrets);
```